# Integral of a sum dependent on the variable of integration

Tags: integration, summation, stochastic-differential-equations, point-processes

Imagine I have a process given by SDE
$$ d\lambda_t = \kappa (\lambda_\infty - \lambda_t)dt + \delta_{1} dN_t $$

where $\lambda_\infty$ is a constant and $N_t$ is a poisson counting process.

Solving this SDE using substitution  $ \tilde{\lambda}_t = e^{\kappa t} \lambda_t$ I get 
$$ \lambda_t = \lambda_\infty + (\lambda_0- \lambda_\infty) e^{- \kappa t} + \delta_{1}\sum_{\tau_i<t}  e^{- \kappa (t-\tau_i)}  $$

Now I am interested in
$$\int_0^T\lambda(t) dt =  \int_{0}^{T}\lambda_0(t)dt + \int_{0}^{T} \sum_{\tau_i<t}\delta_{1} e^{-\kappa(t-\tau_i)}dt$$
where $\lambda_0(t)$ is a deterministic part of the process and $\tau_i$ is a set of arrival times (i.e. a-priori known point).

The part I don't know how to correctly  do is the last integral: 
$$\int_{0}^{T} \sum_{\tau_i<t}\delta_{1} e^{-\kappa(t-\tau_i)}dt$$

could someone please explain me how this integral affects the sum?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you clarify what those $\tau_i$ refer to?

Comment: sorry, please see the edit

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier if you rewrite the sum in terms of the unit step function $H(t)$:
$$\sum_{i:\,\tau_i < t} e^{-\kappa(t-\tau_i)} =
\sum_i e^{-\kappa(t-\tau_i)} H(t-\tau_i).$$
The integral of the $i$th term is zero if $\tau_i>T$ and reduces to the integral of $e^{-\kappa(t-\tau_i)}$ from $\tau_i$ to $T$ otherwise:
$$\int_0^T \sum_i e^{-\kappa(t-\tau_i)} H(t-\tau_i) dt =
\sum_i \frac {1 - e^{-\kappa (T - \tau_i)}} \kappa H(T-\tau_i).$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$P(j, \lambda)$ is the probability of obtaining exactly $j$ successes when expected number of successes is $\lambda,$ according to the Poisson distribution.

Therefore, [sampling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661220/estimating-the-parameters-for-a-sum-of-poisson-distributions-each-multiplied-by/2668514#2668514) is the only option.